# Do I need to format my external SD Card?

Tags: external-sd, formatting

I have a Samsung Galaxy S 5 and will be adding a Class 10, 64 Gig micro SDXC UHS-1 Card. I've seen people refer to formatting an SD card. How do I know if that's necessary in my case?

*Edit: I should have said it's a brand new, unused card.

Comment: *Edit: I should have said it's a brand new, unused card.

Answer (score 1):

Not to remain in any doubt, its the best practice to get your card formatted from within your android device.  In setting... storage settings you are going to find the options to do so.

Answer (score 0):

It is not necessary to format your SD card, sometimes the SD card may not be formatted correctly or may have some virus on it, so it is generally advised to format it and then use it. If there is some important data on it or if your are feeling lazy, just put the card in and see if it works or not. If it does not then you need a format; if it does then there is no need to format.

Hope this helps!

Answer (score 0):

Its generally l good idea to so format your card once it begins to get above 3/4 full or around once every 3 months if you use it frequently (every day). Over time your card collects small fragments of erased images. The accumulative effect of fragment build up begins to reduce memory and slows performance. This also makes the card more likely to become infected by harmful viruses that can cause corruptions and loss of important files. (In which case you'll need to format the card anyways just to rid the SD card of the virus).
  Lastly, and I mean no disrespect but you can never harm your SD card with a simple format. That's nonsense. Its actually quite the opposite. Formatting is recommended and often even encouraged. Don't listen to anyone who says otherwise.